# How to write lambda function for counting occurrence in a string in Python sort()

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I'm trying to write a lambda function (still new to functional programming style of Python). I have a list like this:

```
cur_list = [b'1z1zzz\r\n', b'1z1z1zzz\r\n', b'1z1z1zzz\r\n', b'zzzz\r\n', b'1zzzz\r\n']
```

I want to sort the list by the number of occurrence of '1' in each of them. So in the above list, the correct (sorted) solution would be like this:

```
cur_list = [b'zzzz\r\n', b'1zzzz\r\n', b'1z1zzz\r\n', b'1z1z1zzz\r\n', b'1z1z1zzz\r\n']
```

What lambda function can be inserted into the following snippet of code to efficiently sort by the occurrence of '1' in a given list of string?

```
cur_list.sort(key=#####what lambda function to insert here)
```

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @njzk2 At the time of the question, I am still learning how to use lambda (new concept for me). Yes, I eventually figured out how to do it and shared it as a comment below as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be:

```
lambda x: x.count('1')
```

Of course, as what you have seems like an array of byte strings, you might want this:

```
lambda x: x.count(b"1")
```

Comment: Don't decode. Bytes objects have the same methods as strings, they just expect bytes. Just use `lambda x: x.count(b"1")`

Comment: That does look cleaner and should also be faster, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If anyone is wondering the full code as an answer, this is what I got:
cur_list.sort(key=lambda x: str(x).count('1'))
or just like what @juanpa.arrivillaga suggested:
cur_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.count(b'1'))

Thank you all!

Comment: @user1330974 just for fun, try this: `import functools, operator`; `from collections import Counter` ; `count = functools.reduce(operator.add,map(Counter , cur_list))` ; `{chr(k):v for k,v in counts.items()}`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga My functional programming knowledge in Python is not that advanced (and therefore, I posted this newbie question and got a few downvotes...) Thank you for sharing another way of doing things. :)